# Gitolite doesn't respect rules when accessed through httpd

Tags: git, gitolite

I convinced the office that we should move to Git. Because we're just starting, I set up a git server using plain git and https in front of it using nginx. We *don't* use gitlab or something like that - for now.

One of the questions I got is whether it would be possible to restrict access to specific branches (especially master) for new colleagues. It would have saved us a lot of trouble in the past :-)

During my search for a solution, I found [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html) very promising so I tried it out and set it up. I got git up and running through gitolite so I started to dig into the rules.

However, I cannot get them right. It seems like gitolite ignores [the second check](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#access-control-rule-matching)

My `gitlolite-admin/conf/gitolite.conf` looks like this (I had a more complex one but while debugging I stripped it down to the bare minimum)

```
@starters   =   auric

# project groups
@protected  =   master$

repo gitolite-admin
    RW+     =   admin

repo testing
    RW+     =   @all

repo playground
    R                =   @starters       # allow read from protected
    -   @protected   =   @starters       # deny anything else
    RW+              =   @starters       # allow everything on other branches
```

In the docs it is specified that you can [trace the access control decision](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#tracing-the-access-control-decision).

output of `gitolite access -s playground auric` is this

**pull access**

```
$ gitolite access -s playground auric R master
legend:
    d => skipped deny rule due to ref unknown or 'any',
    r => skipped due to refex not matching,
    p => skipped due to perm (W, +, etc) not matching,
    D => explicitly denied,
    A => explicitly allowed,
    F => denied due to fallthru (no rules matched)

  A        gitolite.conf:14         R                =   @starters       # allow read from protected

refs/.*
```

**push access**

```
$ gitolite access -s playground auric W master

  p        gitolite.conf:14         R                =   @starters       # allow read from protected
  D        gitolite.conf:15         -   @protected   =   @starters       # deny anything else

W refs/heads/master playground auric DENIED by refs/heads/master$
```

**rewind push access**

```
$ gitolite access -s playground auric + master
  p        gitolite.conf:14         R                =   @starters       # allow read from protected
  D        gitolite.conf:15         -   @protected   =   @starters       # deny anything else

+ refs/heads/master playground bert.van.dooren DENIED by refs/heads/master$
```

**push access on another branch**

```
$ gitolite access -s playground bert.van.dooren W anyotherbranch
  p        gitolite.conf:14         R                =   @starters       # allow read from protected
  r        gitolite.conf:15         -   @protected   =   @starters       # deny anything else
  A        gitolite.conf:16         RW+              =   @starters       # allow everything on other branches

refs/.*
```

exactly what I expected it to be.
and indeed, this is what I see in `~/.gitolite/logs` after executing these commands (I stripped the date here):

```
32205   cli     gitolite        access  -s      playground      auric W       master
32205           system,/home/git/gitolite/src/commands/access,-s,playground,auric,W,master
32205           system() failed,/home/git/gitolite/src/commands/access,-s,playground,auric,W,master,-> 256
```

However, when I actually start using git and perform a push (and even a rewind push) through httpd, all commands are allowed and I see this in the logs

```
32196   http    ARGV=auric    SOC=git-receive-pack 'playground.git'   FROM=10.0.13.105
32196   pre_git playground      auric W       any     refs/.*
32196           system,git,http-backend
32196   END
```

as if only check 1 is done but check 2 never comes.

What do I miss here?

**edit** I'm using gitolite3. I know some answers are around about adding the rule `R   master   =   @starters` but then gitolite gives me the warning that that rule doesn't make any sense. It is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The gitolite dev notes](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/dev-notes.html) mention the `pre-git` step as being the log line which appears when the first access check succeeds (i.e., before `git-upload-pack` or `git-receive-pack` is called).

However, the `update` step is not listed in the log: it is the step which appears when the second access check succeeds (i.e., when the `update` hook decides to allow the push).

That means the [update hook](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/lib/Gitolite/Hooks/Update.pm) for that repo might not be correctly in place (symlink in each repo hooks folder to the gitolite update script).
A [`gitolite setup`](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#setup) is supposed to take care of those links.

Actually, the [OP Auric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5094336/auric) comments [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063305/gitolite-doesnt-respect-rules-when-accessed-through-httpd/40064085#comment67407394_40064085):

> While the `update` hook was in place and I actually did use `gitolite setup`, **I did this with another user**.
>
> Since I couldn't get `fcgiwrap` configured to run under another user, I had to make sure `gitolite` was installed under user `git`, but was executable using user `www-data`.
> I used [**`bindfs`**](http://bindfs.org/docs/bindfs.1.html) for this purpose.
> But since I ran `gitolite setup` under user `git`, the `update` hook was symlinked to `/home/git/.gitolite/...` in stead of `/opt/gitolite/.gitolite/...`
> So now I re-ran setup with `/opt/gitolite` as `$HOME` so that the symlink is correct.

Comment: I've been spending hours on this and you directed me to the correct answer. While the update hook was in place and I actually did use `gitolite setup`, I did this with another user.

Comment: Since I couldn't get `fcgiwrap` configured to run under another user, I had to make sure gitolite was installed under user `git` but was executable using user `www-data`. I used `bindfs` for this purpose. But since I ran `gitolite setup` under user `git`, the `update` hook was symlinked to `/home/git/.gitolite/...` in stead of `/opt/gitolite/.gitolite/...`

So now I re-ran setup with `/opt/gitolite` as `$HOME` so that the symlink is correct.

Thank you!

Comment: @Auric Well done! I have included your comments in the answer for more visibility.